# Automatically log out while user inactive for 3 minutes in a page javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I created one tab A, B, C. Each tab has a html page. If I click 1st tab, I have set a timeout function(javascript) for automatic logout. If I am clicking 2nd tab,the same timeout function running. But I want to stop /reset the 1st tab timer.

```js
function timeout(){
 var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //seconds
 var _idleSecondsTimer = null;
 var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

 document.onclick = function() {
     _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
 };

 document.onmousemove = function() {
     _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
 };

 document.onkeypress = function() {
     _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
 };

 _idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

 function CheckIdleTime() {
      _idleSecondsCounter++;
     
     if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
         window.clearInterval(_idleSecondsTimer);
         alert("Time expired!");
         document.location.href = "logout.php";
     }
 }
}

function opentab1(){
     document.getElementById("tab1").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="tab1.php" ></object>';
}

function opentab2(){
     document.getElementById("tab2").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="tab2.php" ></object>';
}

function opentab3(){
     document.getElementById("tab3").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="tab3.php" ></object>';
}
function opentab4(){
     document.getElementById("tab4").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="tab4.php" ></object>';
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="tab1" onload="timeout()" onclick="opentab1()">
</div>
<div class="tab2"  onload="timeout()" onclick="opentab2()">
</div>
<div class="tab3"  onload="timeout()" onclick="opentab3()">
</div>
<div class="tab4"  onload="timeout()" onclick="opentab4()">
</div>

// loading an php file using on click function
<div class="container" id="tab1"></div>
<div class="container" id="tab2"></div>
<div class="container" id="tab3"></div>
<div class="container" id="tab4"></div>


</body>
```

Thanks in advance. Please guide.

Comment: try put `var _idleSecondsTimer = null` on the outside of timeout() function

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of setTimeout().

The clearTimeout() method clears a timer set with the setTimeout() method.

The ID value returned by setTimeout() is used as the parameter for the clearTimeout() method.

**Note**: To be able to use the clearTimeout() method, you must use a global variable when creating the timeout method:

```
Syntax:
    myVar = setTimeout("javascript function", milliseconds);
```

Then, if the function has not already been executed, you will be able to stop the execution by calling the clearTimeout() method.

```
Example:

var myVar;

function myFunction() {
   myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}


 In your case: 
  window.timeout1 = setTimeout(function() {
        _idleSecondsCounter++;
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
             window.clearInterval(_idleSecondsTimer);
             alert("Time expired!");
             document.location.href = "logout.php";
        }
  }, 1000);

 function stopTimeout1() {
        clearTimeout(window.timeout1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the timer whenever a new tab is clicked by editing your methods and stopping the current timer then starting a new one.

You can remove the `onload` from the divs

```
<div class="tab1" onload="timeout()" onclick="opentab1()">
```

to

```
<div class="tab1" onclick="opentab1()">
```

And then in your functions for retrieving the tab content, for example `opentab1()` edit them like the function below

```
function opentab2(){
     //clear the previous timer
     clearInterval(interval_name);

     //start a new timer
     timeout();

     document.getElementById("tab2").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="tab2.php" ></object>';
}
```